# Function properly defined and working but not printing results in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently wrote a simple function that gets the present value of an asset, the function PV works properly and I have tested it. The function prints well in my pv file. However, when I run this code in the main file it does not print the output to the terminal and just closes after taking the inputs. Is there a reason for this? For reference the functions just perform some simple mathematics problems.

Below is a minimal reproduction, both files are in the same folder.
in file_x you have a function that works like this:

```
def func(w,x,y,z):
    z1 = w/(1 + (x/100))**(y*z)
    print(z1)
    return 0
```

this function is then imported into another file which is written like so

```
from file_x import func

w = int(input("Future Value: "))
x = float(input("ROR: "))
y = float(input("# of periods: "))
z = float(input("# of payment per anum: "))

func(w,x,y,z)
```

My problem is that when I run the 2nd file it takes the inputs properly but does not print the result from the function. Hope it was explained properly

Comment: Looks like it all lies in `PV`, as what are seen in the above code are just inputs, which when printed would essentially print without any issues. One has to take a look at the code in `PV` to understand the issue

Comment: We can't help you at all without this being a [mre], what do you expect us to do with what you've given us? Does `PV` itself print out the result? Does it just *return* the result? If so latter, why do you expect something to be printed if you're not using `print()`?

Comment: Why do you think `PV` should write to a file *and* to your terminal?

Answer (score 2):

In interactive mode an *unused* expression (here `PV(w,x,y,z)` which does returns a value and that value is not used) is printed to the terminal, because it is a common way to just display expression values.

But when you run a script in a non interactive mode (`python script.py`) then those unused expression are just discarded. As a general rule, you should never have such an *unused* expression in a script, because the behaviour will depend on the interactive mode of the interpretor.

So you should be explicit:

```
_ = PV(w,x,y,z)     # value will be discarded even in interactive mode
```

or

```
print(PV(w,x,y,z))  # value will be printed even in non interactive mode
```